# distribute values of list 1 unequal lenth over list 2 in linear/evenly fashion

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, math

I have 2 `List<float>` of **unequal** length.

**Scores** and **Grades**.

Depending on the configuration one or the other list is greater than the other.

There are 2 scenarios:

**Use case 1:** 60 scores and 50 grades - 1 to 6 with tenth grades -

I have to distribute 60 scores over 50 grades in an even way.
Thus many grades will have multiple related consecutive scores (1:N relation concerning data structure)

**Use case 2:** 40 scores and 50 grades - 1 to 6 with tenth grades -

I have to distribute 40 scores over 50 grades in an even way.
Thus 10 grades must be removed (50 - 40) evenly to get a 1:1 relation data structure between scores and grades.

What algorithm`s are available to me that I can solve the problem with C#?

I have written down here the result data I would expect to look like when the implemented algorythm is run.

Use case 1 sample result data:

```
Scores  Grade
0   6
1   5,9
2 - 3   5,8
4   5,7
5   5,6
6   5,5
7   5,4
8 - 9   5,3
10  5,2
11  5,1
12  5
13  4,9
14 - 15 4,8
16  4,7
17  4,6
18  4,5
19  4,4
20 - 21 4,3
22  4,2
23  4,1
24  4
25  3,9
26 - 27 3,8
28  3,7
29  3,6
30  3,5
31  3,4
32 - 33 3,3
34  3,2
35  3,1
36  3
37  2,9
38 - 39 2,8
40  2,7
41  2,6
42  2,5
43  2,4
44 - 45 2,3
46  2,2
47  2,1
48  2
49  1,9
50 - 51 1,8
52  1,7
53  1,6
54  1,5
55  1,4
56 - 57 1,3
58  1,2
59  1,1
60  1
```

Use case 2 sample result data:

```
Score   Grade
0   6
1   5,9
2   5,8
3   5,6
4   5,5
5   5,4
6   5,3
7   5,1
8   5
9   4,9
10  4,8
11  4,6
12  4,5
13  4,4
14  4,3
15  4,1
16  4
17  3,9
18  3,8
19  3,6
20  3,5
21  3,4
22  3,3
23  3,1
24  3
25  2,9
26  2,8
27  2,6
28  2,5
29  2,4
30  2,3
31  2,1
32  2
33  1,9
34  1,8
35  1,6
36  1,5
37  1,4
38  1,3
39  1,1
40  1
```

C# converted code for y = f(x) ;-)

```
  int x, y, accum;
            int scores = 33;
            int grades = 51;
            float[] gradesArray = new float[grades];
            float[] scoresArray = new float[scores];

            for (y = 0; y < grades; y++)
                gradesArray[y] =   6.0f - y / 10.0f;

            accum = scores / 2;
            y = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < scores; x++)
            {
                scoresArray[x] = gradesArray[y];
                accum += grades;
                while (accum >= scores)
                {
                    y++;
                    accum -= scores;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Algorithms are not language specific. You should edit the question to remove the C# references. It might also give you a larger audience that will view your question.

Comment: I think you should has a list<Student> students.  Each student should have a grade which comes from a List of scores.  public class Student {string name; float grade; List<float> scores;}

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm).

Comment: @jdweng This is already done and works. My question is about the algorithm available.

Comment: @user3386109 It might go into that direction. But I am not sure where I really can apply the line drawing algo on my scenario. A line is much more complicated concerning the structure. I am rather looking more for a LIST distribution algorithm.

Comment: @MattRowland I also appreciate the advice of c# users already might have done this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `gradesArray` is an input array indexed by `y`, and `scoresArray` is the output array indexed by `x`. To generate the output array, for each index in the output array, you need to select the corresponding value from the input array. In pseudo-code:

```
scoresArray[x] = gradesArray[y]   where y = f(x)
```

In words, each output value `scoresArray[x]` is taken from location `y` in the input array `gradesArray[y]`, where `y` is some function of `x`. And what is that function? Well it's a line.

Here's some sample code that uses a [line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm) to solve use case 1:

```
int x, y, accum;
int scores = 61;
int grades = 51;
float[] gradesArray = new float[grades];
float[] scoresArray = new float[scores];

for (y = 0; y < grades; y++)
    gradesArray[y] = 6.0f - y / 10.0f;

accum = (scores-1) / 2;
y = 0;
for (x = 0; x < scores; x++)
{
    scoresArray[x] = gradesArray[y];
    accum += (grades-1);
    y += accum / (scores-1);
    accum %= (scores-1);
}
```

To adapt the code for use case 2, just change `int scores = 61` to `int scores = 41`.

Comment: Interesting y = f(x) magic, 20 years ago ;-) There are scenarios where I get last element of output array a 1.1 grade but not a 1.0 grade. This wrong behavior starts when I use: int dx = 33 or lower;  int dy = 51; when I use dx = 34 or higher I have the 1.0 grade as last element of the output array. You have any idea what it could be? I posted above your c to my c# converted code. Maybe its a rounding error? I will have to debug that! Else thank you very much, you made that my interest for math increased again

Comment: Or is this "bug" about the missing 1.0 grade in the output array due to the naive line-drawing algorithm? Would another algorythm like Wu`s or Bresenham`s algo be better?

Comment: Maybe this "bug" is also due to from your wikipedia link:"... but if  dx < dy (i.e., slope greater than 1), the line becomes quite sparse with lots of gaps,..." Maybe the missing 1.0 is one of the missing gaps because dx = 33 is < dy = 51 ?!

Comment: @Elisabeth I have to think about it and get back to you later. Perhaps the slope of the line should be `(dy-1)/(dx-1)` instead of `dy/dx`.

Comment: @Elisabeth lol, nothing's going to get done in Europe for a whole month :) Turns out the slope was wrong. I've updated the answer (and fixed the variables to match your C# translation).

Comment: Pretty much you changed! how did you find the accum %= stuff? I can not find that in the line draw algo! Seems my test cases are all greeen, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Elisabeth You're welcome, glad I could help. The `%=` stuff is an optimization of the `while` loop that I had before. The `while` loop was doing division by repeated subtraction. Which is ok for slopes less than 1, but can be bad for slopes much larger than 1. The reason you don't see that in line drawing algorithms is because they always limit the slope to `<= 1`.

Comment: Thanks again for explanation. Have a nice day :-)